# Tighten a mean inequality

Tags: inequality, means

For a given real finite series, say $\{x_n\}$, and a subset of this series $\{y_m\}$ ($m < n$), that is a subsequent serie where some terms of $\{x_n\}$ have been withdrawn. If we would to compare and bound difference between series means, is there a tighter inequality than:

$$
|\bar{x} - \bar{y}| \leq \max(\{x_n\}) - \min(\{x_n\})
$$

Or is it the only thing we can say about it.

Comment: You are not going to do much better than that. Take a million values near 0 and 10 near 1, so the original mean is almost 0. Now delete all the values near 0 and the mean moves to 1.

Comment: Yes that is the kind of argument I was thinking about. But I wonder if someone else have other ideas, if we know about this special case, but there might have other special case that could be interesting.

Comment: The right side can be improved to $(1-\frac{m}{n})(\max x_n-\min x_n)$, is something like that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Apple Yes, that is better, would you mind make an answer of your comment showing how you get this results, thank you.

Comment: @almagest Actually the inequality can be tighten, in your example, this will not make a great difference, but it can be tighten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality can be slightly strengthened to:
$$|\bar{y}-\bar{x}|\leq \left(1-\frac{m}{n}\right)(\max\{x_n\}-\min\{x_n\})$$
Suppose $S\subset \{1, \cdots, n\}$ is the size $m$ set of indices corresponding to the $y_i$. Then note that:
\begin{align*}
n|\bar{x}-\bar{y}|&=\left|\sum_i x_i-\sum_{i\in S}\frac{n}{m}x_i\right| 
\\ &=\left|\sum_{i\notin S}x_i-\frac{n-m}{m}\sum_{i\in S}x_i\right|
\\ &=\left|\sum_{i\notin S}(x_i-\bar{y})\right|
\\ &\le \sum_{i\notin S}\left|x_i-\bar{y}\right|
\\ &\le (n-m)(\max\{x_n\}-\min\{x_n\})\end{align*}
and dividing by $n$ gives the required result. This is sharp when the $x_i$ take on just two values, and all instances of one of the two values are selected for the subsequence $y_i$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.